# How to choose W in Pearson's PCA derivation?

Tags: matrix-decomposition, trace, svd, singular-values, principal-component-analysis

Given that $U\Lambda V^t$ is the SVD decomposition of Y $(Y=U\Lambda V^t)$, and we have to choose k singular values ($\sigma _i$) for the sake of dimensionality reduction, prove that:

$trace(Y^tWW^tY)=trace(V\Sigma U^tWW^tU\Sigma V^t)$

is maximized when the columns of W are colinear with the k columns of U, which are associated with the k largest singular values .

Comment: Proving this statement is equivalent to proving the [EYM theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Proof_of_Eckart%E2%80%93Young%E2%80%93Mirsky_theorem_(for_Frobenius_norm)).